# MikTeX cannot compile when breqn package included

Tags: breqn

I'm seeking for automatic line breaking of math expressions (the example bellow), best recommended option seems `breqn` package. After MikTeX installed **mh** packages, MikTeX cannot build an output (I use TeXnic Center editor) (the text content is shortened):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article} 
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[czech]{babel}
    \usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{amsmath,breqn}
    \usepackage[fontsize=12]{scrextend}
    \DeclareMathSizes{12}{16}{16}{16}
    \pagestyle{headings}
    \linespread{1}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,pdfnewwindow=true,urlcolor=blue}
    \begin{document}

    \section{Nadpis}\label{sec:nadpisa}
    Text pod nadpisem.
    \subsection{Podnadpis}\label{sec:podnadpisa}
    Text pod podnadpisem.
    \subsubsection{Podpodnadpis}\label{sec:podpodnadpisa}
    Text pod podpodnadpisem.

    \begin{multline}
    t_{2}x_{1}cos\alpha+t_{2}y_{1}sin\alpha+t_{2}z_{1}sin\gamma cos\alpha-t_{2}z_{1}sin\alpha sin\beta-t_{3}x_{1}cos\alpha-t_{3}y_{1}sin\alpha-t_{3}z_{1}sin\gamma cos\alpha+t_{3}z_{1}sin\alpha sin\beta-t_{1}x_{2}cos\alpha-t_{1}y_{2}sin\alpha-t_{1}z_{2}sin\gamma cos\alpha+t_{1}z_{2}sin\alpha sin\beta+ t_{1}x_{3}cos\alpha+t_{1}y_{3}sin\alpha+t_{1}z_{3}sin\gamma cos\alpha-t_{1}z_{3}sin\alpha sin\beta+ t_{3}x_{2}cos\alpha+t_{3}y_{2}sin\alpha+t_{3}z_{2}sin\gamma cos\alpha-t_{3}z_{2}sin\alpha sin\beta- t_{2}x_{3}cos\alpha-t_{2}y_{3}sin\alpha-t_{2}z_{3}sin\gamma cos\alpha+t_{2}z_{3}sin\alpha sin\beta
    \end{multline}
    \end{document}
```

It freezes displaying:
[image: TeXnic Center getting stuck]
without pdf output.
After excluding `breqn` package the error disappear.

After excluding `\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}` it freezes three lines before:
[image: TeXnic Center getting stuck #2]

showing the same error. Is there any solution without rewriting the whole content?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no freezing nor error. However, the `dmath` environment should be used, not `multline`. Also, `hyperref` should be loaded last. And the `\DeclareMathSizes` line doesn't make any sense.

Comment: fwiw, it doesn't freeze for me, with any of latex, pdflatex, xelatex or lualatex (all tl'13 -- i don't have miktex [or even windows]).

Comment: The reason is in my czech diacritics ... after deleting (inputenc, babel, fontenc) it's working fine, just diacritics marks are missing

Comment: @questioner01 Without an example of a document that freezes, we can give very little help.

Comment: As I said, (inputenc, babel, fontenc) is behind it. It's kind of incompatible with breqn. May it be helpful if I place the rest of the document here?

Comment: Why does not \DeclareMathSizes make any sense? How can I change math text size globally?

Comment: @questioner01 Why should you want to change math text size, to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use MiKTeX and breqn does work with babel, buts doesn't cooperate with most math package. You have to use the right environment, which is  `dmath`. However I think `aligned`, used with `\MoveEqLeft` on first line, gives a better result. I give an example of both.

You'll have less problems if you use `XeLaTeX` and `polyglossia`. No more loading inputenc nor fontenc. The syntax for loading polyglossia with the Czech language is commented in my preamble; if you want to test, all you have to do is uncommenting these two lines and commenting the babel loading line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,leqno]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\setmainlanguage{czech}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage[IL2]{fontenc}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools,breqn}
\usepackage[fontsize=12]{scrextend}
\DeclareMathSizes{12}{16}{16}{16}
\pagestyle{headings}
\linespread{1}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true,linkcolor=black,pdfnewwindow=true,urlcolor=blue}
\begin{document}

\section{Nadpis}\label{sec:nadpisa}
Text pod nadpisem.
\subsection{Podnadpis}\label{sec:podnadpisa}
Text pod podnadpisem.
\subsubsection{Podpodnadpis}\label{sec:podpodnadpisa}
Text pod podpodnadpisem.

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\MoveEqLeft[3] t_{2}x_{1}\cosα + t_{2}y_{1}\sinα + t_{2}z_{1}\sinγ \cosα \\
 & - t_{2}z_{1}\sinα \sinβ - t_{3}x_{1}\cosα - t_{3}y_{1}\sinα \\
 & - t_{3}z_{1}\sinγ \cosα + t_{3}z_{1}\sinα \sinβ - t_{1}x_{2}\cosα \\
& - t_{1}y_{2}\sinα - t_{1}z_{2}\sinγ \cosα + t_{1}z_{2}\sinα \sinβ \\
 & + t_{1}x_{3}\cosα + t_{1}y_{3}\sinα + t_{1}z_{3}\sinγ \cosα \\
& - t_{1}z_{3}\sinα \sinβ + t_{3}x_{2}\cosα + t_{3}y_{2}\sinα \\
 & + t_{3}z_{2}\sinγ \cosα - t_{3}z_{2}\sinα \sinβ - t_{2}x_{3}\cosα \\
 & - t_{2}y_{3}\sinα - t_{2}z_{3}\sinγ \cosα + t_{2}z_{3}\sinα \sin\beta
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\begin{dmath}
t_{2}x_{1}\cos\alpha+t_{2}y_{1}\sin\alpha+t_{2}z_{1}\sinγ \cos\alpha-t_{2}z_{1}\sinα \sin\beta-t_{3}x_{1}\cos\alpha-t_{3}y_{1}\sin\alpha-t_{3}z_{1}\sinγ \cos\alpha+t_{3}z_{1}\sinα \sin\beta-t_{1}x_{2}\cos\alpha-t_{1}y_{2}\sin\alpha-t_{1}z_{2}\sinγ \cos\alpha+t_{1}z_{2}\sinα \sin\beta+ t_{1}x_{3}\cos\alpha+t_{1}y_{3}\sin\alpha+t_{1}z_{3}\sinγ \cos\alpha-t_{1}z_{3}\sinα \sin\beta+ t_{3}x_{2}\cos\alpha+t_{3}y_{2}\sin\alpha+t_{3}z_{2}\sinγ \cos\alpha-t_{3}z_{2}\sinα \sin\beta- t_{2}x_{3}\cos\alpha-t_{2}y_{3}\sin\alpha-t_{2}z_{3}\sinγ \cos\alpha+t_{2}z_{3}\sinα \sin\beta
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I remember the indentation can be configured in breqn

Comment: @daleif: I didn't find information about that in the doc. But I don't know well `breqn`…

Comment: Har about the indentstep key? See section 10. Not sure if it works

Comment: Thanks, indeed the simplest solution! Breqn works fine with polyglossia in xelatex.

Comment: @daleif: I tested the indentstep key, which I didn't know of. Unfortunately it shifts the whole group.